# Flash movie not looping (even with loop parameter set to "true")

Tags: flash, loops, parameters, embed

I have the following embedded flash code:

```
<object width="647" height="483" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"> 
<param name="salign" value="lt" /> 
<param name="quality" value="high" />   
<param name="scale" value="noscale" /> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> 
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="http://domain.com/movie.swf" />  
<embed width="647" height="483" quality="high" scale="noscale" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://domain.com/movie.swf" wmode="transparent"> 
</embed>
</object>
```

I've been trying to get it to loop after it finishes playing, but it doesn't seem to work even with the "loop" parameter set to "true."  I read online that there may be something with the flash file (exporting from the original .fla), but this is actually a .flv file that I imported into Flash, and exported as an .swf file.

Any ideas would be really helpful!  Thanks.

Comment: Using the component inspector whilst having the video (FLVPlayback component) selected I believe there should be an option to automatically replay the video once it's completed.

Comment: @MartyWallace I got to the Component Inspector, but I wasn't able to find anything on looping?

Comment: you will have better results if you use SWFObject to embed your flash. Also try taking out <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> as this mode can cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer here which worked like a charm:
http://groups.google.com/group/macromedia.flash/browse_thread/thread/7e1cc960a1ba9f29/dad99bda911f8d71

Thanks for looking at it though!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

1. Look at [`autoRewind`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#autoRewind)
2. Look at a combination of [`VideoEvent.COMPLETE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event%3acomplete) and [`seek()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#seek%28%29)

A copy&paste example for the latter:

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoEvent;

YOUR_VIDEO_INSTANCE_NAME.addEventListener("complete", _replay);

function _replay(e:VideoEvent):void
{
    var vid:FLVPlayback = FLVPlayback(e.target);

    vid.seek(0);
    vid.play();
}
```

Comment: Actually I checked the options in Flash, and "autoRewind" was already set to "true" in the Component Inspector.  The second option I'm not sure how to implement?  I'm afraid I'm still new to Flash and Actionscript.  Where do I insert this code?

Comment: You'll be able to place this code on the frame in the timeline where your video is sitting.

Comment: Please tag your question more accurately.. Sorry I couldn't help.